# How to deploy React Next (with Tailwind) app using Vercel?

Tags: react, vercel

I have created an app via React Next using Tailwind. Now I want to use [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) to deploy it.

#### What I tried

```bash
> npm run build
> now
```

This, however does not work. Perhaps because the default `build/` folder is not created from this.

#### Q:

How can I do this?

Comment: For general question about programming stackoverflow.com is a better place to search and ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

You need to export the build as well, like this:

```bash
> cd <to root directory of your Reach next project>
> npx next build
> npx next export
> cd out/
> now
```

Notice how the `./out` folder is created from the `npx next export` call and you need to `cd` into it. Inside that folder you need to call Vercel (done via `now`, when you install Vercel you get that binary).